# What if 100 or more cron setup?

Tags: cron

Regarding cron jobs in ubunutu.

> */1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl  --silent http://local001.erp/snippetbucket/scheduler.php
>
> */1 * * * * /usr/bin/curl  --silent http://local002.erp/snippetbucket/scheduler.php>

What if I had similar 100 or 1000 entries in system, how does I got performance ?
Does it works all or fail  to execute some ?

This seems most important to understand when and how execute.

Comment: It depends... on what cron you use and your system specs ;) And you really need to change your approach to this. 1 line that calls a script is all you need. 1 for next loop in that script is good enough to call them all.

Answer (score 2):

Cron will simply execute all lines sequentially. It won't wait for one to exit to launch another. There might be a maximum limit but I doubt it, if you launch too many resource intensive processes, you'll just crash your machine just like you would if you'd run them manually.

If you have enough processes so that the time it takes to launch them all is more than a minute, then the subsequent processes might be launched at the wrong time (`14:01` instead of `14:00` for example). Apart from that, I don't think there will be any other issues.

A better question is why in the world you would want to do that via cron instead of writing a script with your 1000s of curl commands and running the script with cron.

Comment: Nowadays it is unlimited.

Comment: I can't 1000s of curl commands, its because of utilization of cron for each domain in virtualhost and execute scheduler of application in right manner.

Comment: @user1635700 sorry but I didn't understand your comment at all. What domain? What virtualhost? In any case, The Right Way® is to put your curl commands in a script and launch the script with cron.

Comment: I mean, I had 100 domain registered in my virtualhost for website, each website had cron job one URL, so worried about performance.

Comment: @user1635700 that depends on your hardware. Cron can deal with whatever you give it. If you launch too many jobs, that might affect performance, just like if you launched them manually. There's no difference because it's cron. So, if your system can deal with so many parallel jobs launched manually, it can deal with them launched via cron.